# App crashes with fatal error for setting image to CustomViewCell

Tags: swift, io, uicollectionviewcell

I have created an UICollectionView with custom UICollectioViewCell with just an image view. When I try add an image to the image view in the cell it crashes with

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I'm unable to figure out where i'm getting the nil value from.
Below is my code for the CollectionViewController.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(PhotoViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named:"IMG_1635")// The code crashes here....        
    return cell
}

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}

 // Code for Custom Cell
class PhotoViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var cellImageView: UIImageView!
}
```

The app runs fine when on removing the following line `cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named:"IMG_1635")`

Comment: `cell.cellImageView` is and `UIImageView. UIImage(named:"IMG_1635")` is an UIImage.

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu i didn't get you… please can you elaborate ?

Comment: You try to assign an UIImage to a UIImageView: Create a UIImageView with an Image and assign it to cell.cellImageView
Can you try to remove the **weak** keyword from the PhotoViewCell class please.

Comment: Sure thanks will try and let you know…

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu I tried removing weak and also tried assigning using UIImage var and then to cell.cellImageView still it crashes.

Comment: I do not encounter a crash using this code: `// Code for Custom Cell
class PhotoViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  var cellImageView: UIImageView!
}`

and `cell.cellImageView = (UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)))
    cell.cellImageView.image =  UIImage(named: "IMG_1635.gif")`

Comment: you haven't added the cellImageView as IBOutlet right..?

Comment: are you getting the image on the cells by not having it as an outlet. It doesn't crash if the cellImageView is not an IBOutlet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76813/discussion-between-gutenmorgenuhu-and-yaitsme).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named:"IMG_1635")
```

Comment: I'm sorry i had used cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named:"IMG_1635") in my code but missed to add it in the question. This also crashes with the same error